# how to use regex in MVC 3 with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

when i use MVC 3 with razor it's work fine but when i write a regex using @section head{
} that they not work

```
 function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        }
```

it have @ so that's give me error that

> Parser Error Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately. Parser Error Message: "\" is not valid at the start of
>   a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are
>   valid.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A neater option is to escape the @ by placing another @ in front of it (@@)

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
}
```

Comment: 'less keystrokes' != neater.   Actually, jgauffins solution is more readable and safer (think copy/paste)

Answer (score 1):

Add `<text></text>` around the function, it tells Razor to not parse the contents:

```
<text>
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        }
</text>
```

Comment: are text tag remove from page when they render on client side as html

Comment: yes. It's only used by Razor and is removed from the HTML that is returned to the web browser.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, folks, you aren't reading the error, it's complaining about the backslashes, not the @, and  or @{ } don't help.