# Compilation error when using Regex expression with jQuery In ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have try to validate an email like below with jQuery in asp.net mvc like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function validateEmail(sEmail) {
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
      $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#create').click(function() {
        var sEmail = $('#UserName').val();
        if ($.trim(sEmail).length == 0) {
            alert('Please enter valid email address');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (validateEmail(sEmail)) {
            alert('Email is valid');
        }
        else {
            alert('Invalid Email Address');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
    });
</script>
```

While rendering the view i got compilation error **Unexpected character '\'** in that regex pression.How can i resolve this error?

Comment: you just mixing functions, please sepatate it, document.ready() and validateEmail()

Comment: Did you try using the object notation for RegExp, filter = new RegExp(pattern,modifiers); instead of the literal notation filter = /pattern/

Comment: I have separated the function and document.ready now i got the same error.

Comment: The `@` symbol is used by the razor view engine, that's probably throwing something off. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690066/how-to-use-regex-in-mvc-3-with-razor

Comment: Yes.that's the problem. I have put one more @ in that regex expression.Now my problem resolved. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have same error. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4690148/989462) is answer. It works for me. Need use @@ instead of @.

In your case it is:

```
var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got some weirdness with your braces. Specifically, you didn't close your validateEmail function correctly. Here is the corrected Javascript code:

```
    function validateEmail(sEmail) {
        var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
        if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#create').click(function() {
            var sEmail = $('#UserName').val();
            if ($.trim(sEmail).length == 0) {
                alert('Please enter valid email address');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            if (validateEmail(sEmail)) {
                alert('Email is valid');
            }
            else {
                alert('Invalid Email Address');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
```

EDIT: Also, unrelated, you can make that validateEmail function a bit more succinct since test returns a boolean. See as follows:

```
    function validateEmail(sEmail) {
        var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;

        return filter.test(sEmail);
    }
```

Comment: i have tried this but i got the same compilation error.i think the javascript error doesn't generate any compilation error.

Comment: This is Javascript, no compilation is involved. In fact, I'm not sure why this is tagged ASP.net MVC. This is only a Javascript and jQuery question.

Comment: Never.this error is generated by .net.that's why compilation error generate at runtime

Comment: I either think you're misunderstanding something or you're not giving us the whole picture. If you're getting .Net complaining about a backslash, then that's probably because you're not escaping the backslash or something similar. I'm not sure what you are doing that is causing .Net to complain about a backslash when it should be in a JS file or a view, but try adding a backslash before those backslashes in your Regex. Either way, your Javascript code is also invalid and can be fixed with what I posted above.

Comment: i have tried your code exactly what you have posted.I am using ASP.NET MVC4.